# Create custom dialog box using beforeunload event in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events, reload, onbeforeunload

```
useEffect(() => {
    const handlePopstate = (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.returnValue = "Leaving this page might result in data loss.";
    };

    const handleBeforeUnload = (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.returnValue = "Leaving this page might result in data loss.";
    };

    window.addEventListener("popstate", handlePopstate);
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", handleBeforeUnload);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("popstate", handlePopstate);
      window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", handleBeforeUnload, {
        capture: true,
      });
    };
  });
```

Here, I am trying to change the custom message in reload dialog box.But in that dialog, it always says "Changes you made may not be saved.".

In my app, if I submit the application, it will redirect to a third party url.At that time also, the browser says "Changes you made may not be saved." with leave
and cancel button.So, this message confuses the user, they are clicking cancel.They are not redirecting to that page.